# box-shadow works in all browsers but Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome

Original code that puts a drop shadow at the bottom of my home page header (http://gsmile.org/Word-Dev/) in all browsers except Chrome:

```
.page-id-48 #main-header {
box-shadow: 0 1px 10px 0 #000000 !important;
}
```

Revised code, based on other suggestions, but still doesn't work:

```
.page-id-48 #main-header {
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 10px 0 #000000 !important;
-moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 10px 0 #000000 !important;
box-shadow: 0 1px 10px 0 #000000 !important;
}
```

Comment: No repro: https://jsfiddle.net/9us4jv01/ it's working here. You must have other code you're not including.

Answer (score 0):

Do not know exactly why Chrome is behaving like this. At first it looked like the shadow was hidden on page load. In Chrome it works if you set the "spread" value to at least one Pixel instead of zero (I tried in the debugger console).

```
.page-id-48 #main-header {
box-shadow: 0 1px 10px 1px #000000 !important
}
```

Play a bit with different properties on your page.

More info on box-shadow here: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-shadow.asp

This is just for old browsers for a newer Google Chrome this will definitly have no impact:

```
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 10px 0 #000000 !important;
-moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 10px 0 #000000 !important;
```

Answer (score 0):

`.page-id-48 #main-header {
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 10px 1px #666 !important;
}`

looks like you had you height and spread set to zero, just change those values and it should be fine ... I also changed to black to a dark grey for aesthetic reasons